# Standards for software functional testing

Tags: functional-testing

What documented standards for functional testing exists?

I know about the "Standard for Software Component Testing" (BS 7925-2), which is a unit testing standard.

I need something similar but for functional testing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should search through the huge amount of [IEEE standards](http://standards.ieee.org/). Also, check if the  [ISO/IEC 9126-1:2001](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=22749) standard will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

functinal  testing standards makes life easier for use, because these standards can be converted into checklist and application can be tested easily against the checklist.

**LINKS**

```
Check that the link takes you to the page it said it would.
Ensure to have no orphan pages (a page that has no links to it)
Check all of your links to other websites
Are all referenced web sites or email addresses hyper-linked?
If we have removed some of the pages from our own site, set up a custom 404 page that redirects your visitors to your home page (or a search page) when the user try to access a page that no longer exists.
Check all mailto links and whether it reaches properly
```

**FORMS**

```
Acceptance of invalid input
Optional versus mandatory fields
Input longer than field allows
Radio buttons
Default values on page load/reload(Also terms and conditions should be disabled)
Is Command Button can be used for HyperLinks and Continue Links ?
Is all the datas inside combo/list box are arranged in chronolgical order?
Are all of the parts of a table or form present? Correctly laid out? Can you confirm that selected texts are in the "right place?
Does a scrollbar appear if required?
```

**DATA VERIFICATION AND VALIDATION**

```
Is the Privacy Policy clearly defined and available for user access?
At no point of time the system should behave awkwardly when an invalid data is fed
Check to see what happens if a user deletes cookies while in site
Check to see what happens if a user deletes cookies after visiting a site
```

**DATA INTEGRATION**

```
Check the maximum field lengths to ensure that there are no truncated characters?
If numeric fields accept negative values can these be stored correctly on the database and does it make sense for the field to accept negative numbers?
If a particular set of data is saved to the database check that each value gets saved fully to the database. (i.e.) Beware of truncation (of strings) and rounding of numeric values.
```

**DATE FIELD CHECKS**

```
Assure that leap years are validated correctly & do not cause errors/miscalculations.
Assure that Feb. 28, 29, 30 are validated correctly & do not cause errors/ miscalculations.
Is copyright for all the sites includes Yahoo co-branded sites are updated
```

**NUMERIC FIELDS**

```
Assure that lowest and highest values are handled correctly.
Assure that numeric fields with a blank in position 1 are processed or reported as an error.
Assure that fields with a blank in the last position are processed or reported as an error an error.
Assure that both + and - values are correctly processed.
Assure that division by zero does not occur.
Include value zero in all calculations.
Assure that upper and lower values in ranges are handled correctly. (Using BVA)
```

**ALPHANUMERIC FIELD CHECKS**

```
Use blank and non-blank data.
Include lowest and highest values.
Include invalid characters & symbols.
Include valid characters.
Include data items with first position blank.
Include data items with last position blank.
```